# Iterating through shapefile records in GeoTools using a filter

Tags: shapefile, geotools

I have a pretty large shapefile with almost 14,000 polygons in it. It is about 350mb. I am trying to read it with a SimpleFeatureIterator but it doesn't seem to respect the start Index I specify. It does respect the max features so I think I am pretty close to doing this correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        File file = new File("G:\\shapefiles_basins\\WBD_10_Missouri_Region_HU2\\Shape\\WBDHU12.shp");
        FileDataStore myData = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource source = myData.getFeatureSource();

        Query query = new Query();
        query.setMaxFeatures(5);
        query.setStartIndex(3);
        //query.setSortBy(new SortBy[]{SortBy.NATURAL_ORDER});
        //query.setSortBy(SortBy.UNSORTED);
        SimpleFeatureIterator features = source.getFeatures(query).features();

        while(features.hasNext())
        {
            SimpleFeature feature = features.next();
            System.out.println(feature.getID() + ": ");
            boolean firstProp = true;
            for(Property attribute : feature.getProperties())
            {
                // skip printing the geometry
                if(firstProp)
                {
                    firstProp = false;
                    continue;
                }

                System.out.println("\t" + attribute.getName() + ":" + attribute.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        int xx = 10;
    }
}
```

Here is an abbreviated output it generates (I took out the attributes it printed but they were correct for the record IDs):

WBDHU12.1000: 
...

WBDHU12.10000:
...

WBDHU12.10001: 
...

WBDHU12.10002: 
...

WBDHU12.10003: 
...

So it does print out the correct number of records I request but doesn't start at record #3 and it always consistently retrieves the records 1000, 10000, 10001, 10002, and 10003.

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful if you could tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: An update on this. If I take out the query.setStartIndex(3) it prints out the indexes in this order: 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 10001, 10002...

Comment: So it seems that the records are being iterated by considering the record indexes as alpha instead of numeric collating. Also by specifying 3 it somehow truncates the results and removes the records 1-999 from the iteration.  This means that a start index of 1 would skip records 1-9, 2 would skip records 1-99, 3 skips 1-999 etc. This makes the start index unusable in my opinion unless there is something I am missing.

Comment: As a note, feature IDs are treated as strings, not numbers.  It looks like `setStartIndex` is correctly skipping the first three IDs in lexical order.

Can you say more about the problem you are trying to solve and how you might need to page through the data?